# JMeter JDBC - use one row from the table per one test execution

Tags: loops, jdbc, foreach, jmeter

I use JDBC request for selecting data from the SQL table and use it in a test.
In order to get a value from a table and insert into request I use **ForEach** controller

[image]

But when test runs the controller **gets all values from the table in one test** and executes the transaction that number of times that table has values.

[image]

How can I use only one value per test and execute the transaction only once per test?
When I *don't use ForEach controller* the variable doesn't use as well and I see in the request only variable name: *${variable}*

My Debug Sampler picture. Variable name is changed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination in order to inspect the variables produced by the JDBC Request sampler, this way you will be able to choose the variable holding the "interesting" value.

The variables are generated using the following pattern:

```
variable_1=value from 1st row
variable_2=value from 2nd row
...
variable_#=number of rows returned by your query
```

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more details.

So if you want to use the value from first row - use `${variable_1}`, from 2nd row - `${variable_2}`, if you want a random value - go for [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like `${__V(variable_${__Random(1,${variable_#},)},)}`. if you want something else - show the output of the Debug Sampler with your "variables" and indicate how you would like to re-use them in the next request(s)

Comment: Added screenshot of the debug sampler into the question